# Suppress default handling of Ctrl+O in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keyboard-events

I'm trying to suppress IE's default handling of Ctrl+O.

I've got a onKeyDown handler which get's called, but even though I call `event.cancelBubble` and `return false`, the default File|Open command still runs.

btw: this is not critical since I can just pick another key but curious if there might be a way around this.

Comment: You generally can't change the user interface of a browser with JavaScript.

Comment: @RoToRa, it's done all the time. You can ctrl+s in differnt editors for example. Some commands might take precedence by the browser, but in general you can do things like this.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood. I though he wanted to disable Ctrl-O including File/Open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't call `event.cancelBubble`, it's not a method, but a property you can set to `true`.

To prevent the default action of special keys in IE, you also have to set the IE keycode to 0:

```
function keydownHandler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.keyCode = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: has to be registered for `keydown` in IE8. `keyup` doesn't work.

Comment: @lincolnk: Correct. You can't suppress default actions during `keyup`, as by then the action already has taken place. Also see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html#t09

Comment: It was the `e.keyCode=0` I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rick: Ah, that's probably because `e.preventDefault` is present. What happens if you move `e.keyCode = 0;` outside of the condition?

Comment: @Marcel: Still doesn't work in IE 11, even with that change. Haven't found any technique that does work.

Comment: @enigment I don't have IE 11, so I can't help you with that.